# IF AND COUNTIF FUNCTIONS, EXCEL

Tags: excel

The =IF(something = "true"; 1;2) sets a cell equal to 1 if something = true, otherwise the cell is set to 0.
How can I do the same operation for multiple rows?

Comment: Not a software development question, you might have more luck on SuperUser.

Comment: If you have excel-365 then could try `=IF(A1:A500= "true"; 1;2)`

Comment: Or even `=(A1:A500<>"true")+1`

Comment: I am using this order " =IF(COUNTIF(A1:A100; "RED"); 1;2). I have selected the column I want to place either 1 or 2 ( lets say column b).  The result I have is 1 in cell B1 and nothing else. (Microsoft Excel 2007)